# mingw 3.4.5 missing dlfcn.h?

Tags: mingw

is it possible that my mingw 3.4.5 installation is faulty? or is this provided on some other library floating around?

in case you are wondering, dlfcn.h is where stuff like dlopen and dlclose are defined, so it should be pretty standard

Comment: Funny, I was having this problem recently too.

Comment: MinGW is not POSIX compliant, by design. It is meant to be a native windows toolchain. Use Cygwin for POSIX compliant tools for win32.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not in my MinGW 3.4.5 installation, so I doubt your installation is faulty.  I suppose the the MinGW maintainers expect you to use the Win32 functions supporting dynamic loading (`LoadLibrary()`, `GetProcAddress()`, etc.).

Answer (score 12):

[dlfcn-win32](http://code.google.com/p/dlfcn-win32/) is a wrapper for dlfcn around the win32 dll functions

Answer (score 3):

mingw is an implenentation of a compiler for windows (a gcc port) implementing the win32 API.  The functions in dlfcn.h (dlopen/dlsym et. al.) are POSIX, not windows, so no win32 implementation exists.  There may be a wrapper in msys or cygwin, but I fear that the differences between the windows DLL and the ELF shared library mechanisms means you'll simply need to port to the windows APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and after installing dlfcn-win32-r19.tar.bz2 on windows under cygwin shell, the problem was solved.

https://code.google.com/p/dlfcn-win32/downloads/detail?name=dlfcn-win32-r19.tar.bz2

I hope this help other guys.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but nonetheless still relevant today, regardless of the version of GCC from MinGW.org which may be in use.

Those who have observed that MinGW is really intended for use with the native Win32 APIs, based on LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress(), rather than the POSIX specific APIs declared in dlfcn.h, are completely correct; thus, MinGW.org has not traditionally provided any implementation of the dlfcn.h API functions.

However, as of mingwrt-3.21, I needed to implement MinGW functionality which is akin to the POSIX use of dlsym() on the RTLD_DEFAULT address space.  Consequently, from this version of the MinGW runtime onwards, I intend to maintain a conforming implementation of the POSIX dlfcn.h APIs, as a wrapper around the LoadLibrary(), GetProcAddress(), and PSAPI.DLL native Win32 APIs.

Comment: Do please note that the MinGW implementation of dlfcn is **not** derived from dlfcn-win32, (mentioned in another answer, and now to be found on on GitHub).  It is a new implementation, written from scratch, to offer more comprehensive POSIX feature compliance, (which MinGW needed); it is also distributed under the more permissive MIT licence, rather than GPL-2.

Comment: You write "intent" did you already start?

Comment: @D4v1dW3bb, the implementation is long since complete, and, as I wrote, I intend to maintain it for the foreseeable future.  This implementation has been distributed with mingwrt, since version 3.21, and remains functional in the current 5.4.x distributions.  It is compatible with MinGW-GCC-4.x and later; (MinGW-GCC-9.2.0 is current).  Please do not ask me to continue supporting MinGW-GCC-3.4.5; it reached EOL years ago.

Answer (score 0):

dlfcn.h: No such file or directory

To solve this I had to add to the .pro file :

```
DEFINES += _WINDOWS
```