# Check for working C compiler: "cl.exe - skipped" : Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings

When running my build script that uses cmake I am getting the following output during the build process:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.7.5
** Copyright (c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29112.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
```

I've seen in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719568/llvm-build-on-windows-visual-studio-cl-exe-skipped) that this isn't an error, and my code goes onto compile until a different error, but why would the output be "skipped" instead of "works"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's normal in newer CMake versions as the test is skipped because the compiler is known to work because it was able to determine the ABI.

Refer to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/4789